# Issue forming function of parameters with the Cases function

Tags: function, import, wolfram-mathematica

This is my code so far:

```
    k = Import["all.txt.", "Table"];

    Cases[k, {name_, G_, H_, S_, Cp_, V_, a1a_, a2b_, a3c_, c1e__, c2f_, 
omegalan_, cT_} /; name == "compoundname" -> {Cp, G, S}];
```

This imports a table of 2000 different compounds, each having 12 different numerical values. Right now when i alter "compoundname" to for instance "water" the values I desire (here Cp,G and S) will appear for water.

I am trying to alter this to make it so I can type the desired name into a simple function instead by attempting something like this:

```
    HKFparameters[compoundname_] := Cases[k, {name_, G_, H_, S_, Cp_, V_, a1a_, a2b_, a3c_, c1e__, c2f_, omegalan_, cT_} /; name == "compoundname" -> {Cp, G, S}]
```

I have tried modifying this line in multiple ways but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of `HKFparameters` you have included the expression

```
name == "compoundname"
```

This should be

```
name == compoundname
```

since you want to select the case where the name of the compound matches the argument `compoundname` not the string `"compoundname"`.